# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, summation

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges, but $b_n \not=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges? No, I think it's not true. Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then it diverges.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges? No, I think it's not true. $a_n=n$, $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, so $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges.

Comment: Your counterexamples are not good.

Comment: Try proving that $\sum 1/n^p$ converges for all $p>1.$

Comment: Do you assume the sequences are positive? Because if not, take $b_n = (-1)^n$ and $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: Yes I change it.

Comment: @StephenDonovan is it true now?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I change it now, i think it's closer.

Comment: I have calculation mistakes. It's fine I think now.

Comment: @oraora Much better

Comment: @oraora First counterexample is correct. Second one is wrong: $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\neq0$.

Comment: Ok so they are right, now?

Comment: My apologies, I missed the limit being wrong somehow

Answer (score 1):

For the second, take

$$a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$

$$\sum b_n \text{ alternate convergent}$$
$$\sum a_nb_n=\sum \frac 1n\text{ divergent}$$